# Is there a term for a mental prototype changing?

Tags: terminology, psycholinguistics, cognitive-linguistics, prototype-theory

Years ago, if I heard the word *bird* I thought about a sparrow since I live in western Pennsylvania and there are sparrows **everywhere**. But now, if I hear the word *bird* I picture a blue, two-dimensional sparrow. Not quite a Twitter bird, just a sparrow that has lost a dimension and turned blue.

Is there a term to describe a mental prototype changing because of new influences?

Comment: And yes, I'm fully aware this question would also fit on CogSci, but *bird* is a word, and linguistics is about words and rules. So it mostly fits. On a side note, when I was typing this comment, rather than "*bird* is a word," I almost typed "the bird is the *word.*"

Comment: I don't think the fact your example is the word "bird" makes it any more a linguistic question than an ornithological question. It's definitely either a cogsci.SE question that you should tag [tag:terminology] or an english.SE question that you should tag [tag:single-word-requests]. By the way, another term commonly used where you've used ***prototype*** is the adjective ***platonic***.

Comment: Since you are a student of linguistics, your prototype of "bird" may have been influenced by the wug.   https://thelanguagenerds.com/2019/what-is-a-wug/